# Отправка сообщения в телеграмм сразу нескольким пользователям

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Есть телеграм бот. Я могу отправить менеджеру с его помощью уведомление о поступившем заказе с сайта. Вот такой php-скрипт используется у меня на сайте при оформлении заказа.

```
$ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$config['tg_token'].'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$config['tg_users'].'&text=Пользователь '.$order['nick'].' оплатил товар '.$group['name'].', за: '.$amount.' руб.');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Не возвращать ответ
curl_exec($ch); // Делаем запрос
curl_close($ch); // Завершаем сеанс cURL
```

Проблема: менеджера целых три. И нужно отправлять это уведомление всем троим. Соответственно, $tg_user не один, а три. Вопрос: как лучше сделать? Трижды запускать скрипт с разными $tg_user? Или как-то можно по-другому? В API телеги искал, не нашел решения для массовой отправки.
Спасибо!